# How to apply a css rule only to few elements

Tags: css, html

I have the following css entry

```
.plugins-updown .top-panel.plugin header {
    cursor: move;
}
```

This css is applied on so many header elements in my site. However in two header elements, I want to have the cursor as default. So I added a new class only in those two header elements as shown below

```
<div class="top-panel plugin">
<header class="default-cursor">

</header>
</div>

.plugins-updown .top-panel.plugin header .default-cursor {
    cursor: default;
}
```

But when I checked in the Chrome's dev tools, I don't see cursor:default being applied. The inspect element of the dev tools shows that the two specific header elements has the .default-cursor class as part of it, but the css is not applied and the cursor shows as cursor:move as in other header elements.

Thanks

Comment: Does the second CSS code come after the first one?

Comment: Both are part of a single.css file

Answer (score 5):

Connect the `.default-cursor` selector to its element like so:

```
.plugins-updown .top-panel.plugin header.default-cursor {
    cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: I tried that. I even added !important like so: cursor: default !important; But, if I add style="cursor:default" in the <header> element, then it works.

Comment: That is a specificity issue that you didn't mention in the question.  Make sure it's declared **after** the other header rules with the `move` set.  Setting `style="..."` trumps anything in a CSS file, even `!important`.  This article should help:  https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/ or if you're quicker at understanding, try this more direct info source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 0):

You have entered space in between header and cursor-default class. Remove the space and apply the css rule with important. It will work perfectly.